# Identify if a value is appearing for the first time in a column

Tags: sql

I'm trying to identify if the value of a column (let's call it status for now) is appearing for the first time for a given ID, or if it's previously held that value before. If its the first time that the status is equal to 1 or 2, I'd like to return a 1=Y or a 0=N. The results below are what I'm looking to recreate. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks

```
ID  Date      Status First Time

1  1/1/2017     1   Y    
2   1/1/2017    0   N    
3   1/1/2017    0   N    
4   1/1/2017    2   Y    
5   1/1/2017    0   N

1   2/1/2017    0   N   
2   2/1/2017    0   N    
3   2/1/2017    1   Y    
4   2/1/2017    0   N    
5   2/1/2017    1   Y    

1   3/1/2017    2   N    
2   3/1/2017    0   N    
3   3/1/2017    0   N    
4   3/1/2017    1   N    
5   3/1/2017    1   N
```

Comment: give some sample data also corresponding to your expected result ?

Comment: use CASE statements

Comment: Store dates as dates. See [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query). And then get back to us.

Comment: Why do you have `Y` for `3 2/1/2017 1`? Status 1 appeared previously in `1 1/1/2017 1`. Do you mean "first time for the same ID"?

Comment: Three of the four comments above basically mean you need to at minimum begin by defining what you mean by "first".

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya ID, Date, and Status are the sample data, I'm trying to write a sql statement that will return the First Time column

Comment: Order your table by ID, date, and status. Use user-defined variables to hold the ID, date, and status of the previous row. If the current row has the same values, set first time to N, otherwise set it to Y.

Comment: @Barmar sorry for the confusion, yes I meant for the same ID

Comment: @StephenGardner. . . Tag the only DBMS which you are really using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT t1.ID, t1.Date, t1.status
, CASE WHEN firsts.ID IS NULL THEN 'N' ELSE 'Y' END AS `First Time`
FROM theTable AS t1
LEFT JOIN
   (SELECT ID, MIN(Date) AS fDate
   FROM theTable AS t0
   WHERE status IN (1, 2)
   GROUP BY ID
) AS firsts
ON t1.ID = firsts.ID AND t1.status IN (1, 2) AND t1.Date = firsts.fDate
;
```

You can use a subquery to identify the firsts, and join to the original records to "add" that information.

Note: This could lead to some redundant firsts if an ID's first 1 and 2 status values occur on the same day; but the current definition of "first" does't really state which status would be "first".

Comment: My edit is too short to make, but you are missing "THEN" from between "NULL" and 'N'.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this may work for you.  The ROW_NUMBER function ordered by date and partitioned by status will add a counter that, within each group of similar statuses, will increment from 1 according to ascending date.

Combining this with a CASE statement, we can say that the status a 'first time' when that counter is either a 1 or two.

```
SELECT 
    *
    , CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Status] ORDER BY [date]) IN (1,2) THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END
FROM [MY_TABLE]
```

EDIT:
As noted below, this is a SQL Sever solution.  You would make some tweaks to get it in MYSQL.

Comment: You should note that he needs to use MySQL 8.x to get window functions.

Comment: @Barmar. . . Previously that was tagged with `SQL Serever`.

Comment: But that tag was removed a while before you posted.

Comment: @Barmar. . . No op didn't tagged with `MySQL`.

Comment: It was originally tagged with both mysql and sql-server. 10 minutes ago someone removed the sql-server tag.

Comment: @Barmar. . . So, now still not clear whether it  is for `MySQL` or `SQL  Server` untill op tag the right DBMS.

Answer (score 0):

Just check if Status is 1 or 2, and whether there exists a record with the same ID and at an earlier date with Status 1 or 2.

```
select ID, Date, Status,
    case 
        when a.Status in (1,2) and not exists(select * from table b where a.ID = b.ID and b.Status in (1,2) and b.Date < a.Date) then 'Y' 
        else 'N' 
    end as First
from table a
```

Comment: This can be very slow (think quadratic) if your table is large as you are making a scan over the table for each row.

Answer (score 0):

Working solution, if I understand the problem correctly:

*Test Table Creation:*

```
WITH Test (ID, [Date], [Status]) AS (
    SELECT * FROM (
        VALUES
            (1,Convert(datetime, '1/1/2017', 120),1), 
            (2,Convert(datetime, '1/1/2017', 120),0), 
            (3,Convert(datetime, '1/1/2017', 120),0), 
            (4,Convert(datetime, '1/1/2017', 120),2), 
            (5,Convert(datetime, '1/1/2017', 120),0), 
            (1,Convert(datetime, '2/1/2017', 120),0), 
            (2,Convert(datetime, '2/1/2017', 120),0), 
            (3,Convert(datetime, '2/1/2017', 120),1), 
            (4,Convert(datetime, '2/1/2017', 120),0), 
            (5,Convert(datetime, '2/1/2017', 120),1), 
            (1,Convert(datetime, '3/1/2017', 120),2), 
            (2,Convert(datetime, '3/1/2017', 120),0), 
            (3,Convert(datetime, '3/1/2017', 120),0), 
            (4,Convert(datetime, '3/1/2017', 120),1), 
            (5,Convert(datetime, '3/1/2017', 120),1)
    ) AS A (Column1, Column2, Column3)
)
```

*Query:*

```
SELECT id,
    [Date],
    (SELECT [Status] FROM Test b 
        WHERE a.ID = b.ID 
        AND a.[Date] = b.[Date]) AS [Status], 
    CASE WHEN (SELECT MIN([Date]) 
        FROM Test 
        WHERE [Status] IN (1, 2)
        AND ID = a.ID
        GROUP BY ID
    ) = a.[Date] THEN 'Y'
    ELSE 'N'
    END AS FirstTime
FROM Test a 
GROUP BY ID, [Date]
```

Comment: I have to ask. Why a correlated subquery for `status` with `(SELECT [Status] FROM Test b WHERE a.ID = b.ID AND a.[Date] = b.[Date])` instead of just a direct `a.[Status]`?

Comment: Restrictive grouping, and for fun.